# How can I retrieve data from an array which is inside another array and display it in the table?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Using Vue.js , I am able to retrieve and display id,description and location, but why in the tasks column I only have [object Object] in all the rows ?! 
(tasks is an array inside jobs array)

```
<template>
<div>
...
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="column in columns">
        ...
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr v-for="work in jobs">
      <td>{{work["id"]}}</td>
      <td>{{work["description"]}}</td>
      <td>{{work["location"]}}</td>
      <td v-for="tasks in jobs" >{{work["tasks"]}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script> 
export default{

data : function() {
  return{
      columns: ['id', 'description', 'location', 'tasks'],
      jobs: '',
      update: this.getData()    
  }
},

methods: {
//to get data from the backend API
  getData() {
    this.$http
      .get('http://localhost:3001/api', (data) => {
        this.jobs = data["jobs"]
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: I send the GET request in Postman and the data I retrieve, looks like this:]

[image]

Comment: That's because `tasks` is an array of "Objects". What do you want to display there exactly?

Comment: Do you really want a varying number of columns? Or do you want a subtable in the fourth column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over `jobs` and not each task inside the `job's tasks`

You should do something like -

```
        <tr v-for="work in jobs">
          <td>{{work["id"]}}</td>
          <td>{{work["description"]}}</td>
          <td>{{work["location"]}}</td>
          <td v-for="task in work.tasks" >{{task["id"]}} -
 {{task["description"]}} - {{task["location"]}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Or however you want to display there. But the idea should be to iterate on the `tasks` array inside each `work` object

Comment: Thank you Vandesh, I can display the tasks data now, but only the values. more specifically i am trying to display a table as i show in the image above. I think I should use colspan or rowspan, but how exactly !

Comment: That should be a different question tagged as HTML

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly extract the fields that you want to show from `tasks`. Also, the syntax for the nested `v-for` would be something like `task in work.tasks`, so that your `task` points to each task inside of your `tasks` array for each `work`:

```
<tr v-for="work in jobs">

    <td>{{work["id"]}}</td>
    <td>{{work["description"]}}</td>
    <td>{{work["location"]}}</td>

    <td v-for="task in work.tasks">
        {{task["id"]}} <br>
        {{task["description"]}} <br>
        {{task["location"]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```